# Laravel 5.4 not accepting post request in routes

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.4

I have made a ajax call in laravel 5.4 following is the script

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#btnLogin").click(function()
                    {
                        // var username = $('#username').val();
                        // var password = $('#password').val();

                        // var form = new FormData($('.login-form')[0]);
                        var form = $('.login-form').serializeArray();

                        $.ajax({
                                    url: '/login',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    dataType: 'JSON',
                                    data: {form},
                                })
                        .done(function(resp){
                            console.log(resp);
                        })
                        .fail(function(resp){
                            console.log(resp);
                        })
                        .always(function(resp){
                            console.log(resp);
                        });
                    });
            });
    </script>
```

This is my web.php in routes folder

```
<?php
  Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/login', function () {
  return "hello";
  });
```

It is showing the error in console log, i dont know why it is showing this. Firstly it was showing 404 not found then i realized that i had not defined in rotes then i defined in routes then it is showing this error.

```
POST http://www.example.com/login 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

If  access this url through browser direct it is showing `hello` but if i am making through ajax it is not loading.

Comment: Please post your Error Stack Trace you get from POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hitting through browser, you are requesting page with get request, however, through ajax, it goes through post.